# Using ordinary least squares regression with multiple predictor variables on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, regression

I have the following code which is trying to predict a y variable, in this case 'distance', based on multiple predictor variables, which are stored in newdf[cols].

However, when I run the code, I get the outcome: 'Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data)'.

Am I specifying the smf.ols() command in the wrong way?

I would be so grateful for a helping hand.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm 
cols = newdf.drop(['distance', 'duration','short_id'],axis=1)
X = cols
Y = newdf['distance']
X = sm.add_constant(x)
resultmodel = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
print(resultmodel.summary())
```

The first 20 rows of X are:

[image]

The first 20 rows of Y are:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the formula api you have to enter a formula as a string as the first argument. If you just want to enter X and y and use all columns of X, you can use the non-formula API. Basically just replace `smf.ols` with `sm.OLS` in your code.

Comment: I have amended the code above, and it now gives me this error: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data). Might you know why this is?

Comment: Looks like you have some columns in your data frame that can't easily be casted to numpy. Maybe some strings? Without knowing the content of the data frame there's not much I can say about it unfortunately.

Comment: Ah I guess all the NaNs might be a problem. Maybe try to kick the NaN rows out and try again.